# Using raster calculator for subtracting landslide mass from raster topo?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I have a topographic raster data of an area prior to a landslide event. Unfortunately, I don't have a topo-data after the event. So, in order to simulate the landslide event and its run-out distance, I need to subtract the landslide source volume from the main topography raster file.

I have the shape of the landslide source area as a shapefile, and I even have a raster file clipped in the shape of the source file. I have tried to subtract this file from the main file with a uniform depth (let's say 2m) but the result is only on the clipped area.

Is it generally possible to do such calculation (subtraction of selected area) on raster files and, if yes, then how?

[image: raster data with the source shapefile]
[image: the clipped landslide raster file]
[image: the resulting raster after subtraction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a field to the polygon and calculate / edit as the value of 2
2. Convert to raster: Raster-Conversion-Rasterize. Note the settings used. For example use original raster as template extent and original raster pixel size as resolution:
   [image]
3. Subtract created raster from original raster
   [image]

[image]

Comment: Great! thank you so much. This method helped me get the required raster.

Comment: @A.L.Y nice! Could you accept my answer with the checkbox?